# Images not working on some pages but fine on others?

Tags: image, web, path, hyperlink

I have designed a website for a local business but for some reason the images won't work when it's uploaded to the FTP server. They work fine when I view them locally and the paths are exactly the same for the images that don't work and the ones that do?

The website is : www.Neontattooart.com - This image is what it's meant to look like.

http://i47.tinypic.com/155hzte.png

Can post any extra code if needed but most of it is on there.

Thanks in advance. Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a folder names "images" in the root of your website on the FTP?

The image should be available at http://www.neontattooart.com/images/thumbnail.png but it isnt't.

Comment: Yes there is, as on the "about us" the "phil.png" is in there and works fine. I can't seem to understand how one picture will work but the others wont although in the same directory using the exact same paths. x

Comment: http://neontattooart.com/images/logo7.gif - Seems to work fine but won't show as an actual banner?

Comment: Ok. http://www.neontattooart.com/images/ ist available. But there's no thumbnail.png in it

Comment: You have a typo: it's logo7.gif instead of Logo7.gif. You are probably working on Windows locally. Windows seems not to care about upper or lower case

Comment: Good lord. Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't even see that..

Yes I am. As I kept viewing it locally I thought it was fine. Thanks for the advice. I now know that it's not just accepted when not local.